# minimizing a non-linear function when the constraint is not differentiable

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

Minimize the distance from $(x_0, y_0)$ in the 4th quadrant to the curve $y = |x|$

I know that the minimization problem is:

minimize $$f(x,y)= (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2$$
subject to$$ g(x,y) = y - |x|= 0 $$

Since the constraint g(x,y) is not differentiable, how can I use two inequality constraints to solve this problem?

Comment: The most direct approach is to break this into cases for each quadrant $(x_0,y_0)$ might reside.

Comment: Since $(x_0,y_0)$ is in the fourth quadrant, the minimum distance will lie on the arm $y = x$, $y \geq 0$ (why?).